# returned error: query returned more than 10000 results

Tags: node.js, ethereum

I am working on an ethereum project in which I want to store all specific "Transfer" Event emitted values into an excel file. I am able to write it till a certain number of blocks not all as it shows the Error:  returned error: query returned more than 10000 results. I am using an infura account. I have also tried the AlchemyAPI account but got the same error as it supports the results till 10K only. Can anyone tell me how I can resolve it? Or any other web provider which supports more than 10000 results.

```
Error: Returned error: query returned more than 10000 results
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/home/admin1/Desktop/Ethereumevents/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
    at Object.callback (/home/admin1/Desktop/Ethereumevents/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:303:36)
    at /home/admin1/Desktop/Ethereumevents/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/index.js:114:45
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at WebsocketProvider._onMessage (/home/admin1/Desktop/Ethereumevents/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/index.js:102:69)
    at W3CWebSocket._dispatchEvent [as dispatchEvent] (/home/admin1/Desktop/Ethereumevents/node_modules/yaeti/lib/EventTarget.js:115:12)
    at W3CWebSocket.onMessage (/home/admin1/Desktop/Ethereumevents/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:234:14)
    at WebSocketConnection.<anonymous> (/home/admin1/Desktop/Ethereumevents/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:205:19)
    at WebSocketConnection.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at WebSocketConnection.processFrame (/home/admin1/Desktop/Ethereumevents/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:554:26)
    at /home/admin1/Desktop/Ethereumevents/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:323:40
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  data: null
}
```

The Code is given below:

```
code:

async function write_csv(obj) {
  writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.csv', { flags: 'a' }));
  console.log("written",obj)
  writer.end();
};

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(interface, contractAddress);
     
        var Transfer = contract.events.Transfer({fromBlock:5521592}, async function (error, event) {
        console.log(event);
       
  })
  .on('data',async function (event) {console.log("hi",  JSON.stringify(event))

  var res = {From:event.returnValues[0], To:event.returnValues[1], Value:event.returnValues[2]};
  write_csv(res);
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve('done'), 20000));
})
  .on('changed', function (event) {console.log("hi")
  
})
  .on('error', console.error);
```

Comment: The 10k limit is because of your Infura plan. [This answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/87720) on Ethereum StackExchange provides a workaround - see if you can use it with your code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to paginate and throttle your queries because there is a max size limit for JSON-RPC responses.

Unfortunately, because of the brain dead way how Ethereum `eth_getLogs` API implemented, this is not possible. [On Web3.py project there is an example query code that can do Ethereum event fetch pagination, throttling and resume queries in the case of errors](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#advanced-example-fetching-all-token-transfer-events). The example also highlights various obstacles your code needs to overcome.